# QucikBlox: Push Notification not working properly

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to send push notification from Admin panel. It shows message sent successfully but I am **NOT** getting the message as push notification on device.

Also I am not able to send push notification from application.

Code:

```
QBMPushMessage *message = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];

// Send push
[QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.opponent.ID] delegate:self];
```

in delegate method:

```
else if([result isKindOfClass:[QBMSendPushTaskResult class]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        // Success result
        if(result.success)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message sent successfully" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            //[alert show];
            [alert release];

            // Errors
        }
    }
```

Please see below images :
[image]

[image]

Comment: so, what the problem is? you don't see messages on your device?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: yes... not getting on device !

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: ok solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok Solved.

I have to create new development certification according to [How to create APNS certificates.](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates)

Also my previous certificate was Push Notification enabled and working fine with API 1.4. I don't know what was the problem with old certificate !!!

Comment: Do you have an idea with android?My push notification is not working as well.Where I can get APNS cert.?